# WebView getDrawingCache() always returning null

Tags: android, debugging

I'm just fooling around with a webView on API17 and I've come to this problem.

Here's the code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);


webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www2/info.htm");
if (webView.getProgress()==100){
       webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       webView.buildDrawingCache();
       Bitmap bitmap =    Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache());
       webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }
```

After this, I will just play around with the bitmap. The problem is an null pointer exception at the .getDrawingCache. info.htm is displayed correctly in the web view when the progress is at 100. I don't know why the getDrawingCache gives nothing back.

I looked up all stackexchange threads to this problem, but none of the solutions helped me.

Anyone got an idea?

greetings